# Alt+<key> shortcuts for `workbench.action.terminal.split` are passed to terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to override shortcut for `workbench.action.terminal.split`. Default shortcut (`Ctrl+Shift+5`) works fine, but when I change it to shortcut with `Alt` prefix (e.g.  it gets passed to terminal.

I check that shell receives keypresses using `stdbuf -o0 showkey -a`.

Is there a way to make VSCode handle such shortcuts and not pass it to terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was caused by enabling `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell` setting.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151603

Answer (score 0):

There are settings that allow to fine tune weather vscode or terminal handle key bindings; I found them at :

@id:terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell,terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell,terminal.integrated.allowChords

adding workbench.action.terminal.split to the list "Commands To Skip Shell" should do the trick for you

Comment: The problem is that `commandsToSkipShell` already contains `terminal.split` by default. And if shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+5` it works as expected, the problem arises only if shortcut is `Alt+...` (but I tried explicitly add `commandsToSkipShell` option, that didn't help).